# IPhone - View hides behind the status bar

Tags: iphone, view, statusbar, behind

I am trying to add a subview to my iphone window and i have written the following code for that. Problem is that when the splash view or main menu view appears on the screen, it goes behind status bar. I mean the view starts from behind the status bar. Also both view overlap when the main menu view is show after the splash view. Can anyone please help?
Thanks

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
       [window addSubView: [[Resources getResources] getSplashView]];
       [vindow makeKeyAndVisible];
       [self performSelector:@selector(displayMainMenuView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
  }


 -(void) displayMainMenuView {
       [window addSubView: [[Resources getResources] getMainMenuView]];`   
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code which init the view, especially the code with the frame of the view?

Comment: Actually i am creating a window based app using predefined project templates of the xcode. So everything is default. I just changed the those methods i quoted earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just adjust the frame of your main menu like:

```
mainMenuViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f);
```

This will make your view just below the statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `statusBarHidden` to YES when the splash view is displayed

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
       application.statusBarHidden = YES;
       [window addSubView: [[Resources getResources] getSplashView]];
       [vindow makeKeyAndVisible];
       [self performSelector:@selector(displayMainMenuView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
  }
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the reply. The same thing happens when the main menu view is displayed. Is there anyway i can make this view display below the status bar, not behind it? I am working in Window based application.

Comment: If you want the statusBar always hidden set it to hidden in all your .xib files. And add the property "Status bar is initially hidden" set to YES in the Info.plist.

Comment: No i dont want to hide the status bar. I just want to show the status bar and the view should start from below the status bar. I just dont want my view to start from behind the status bar.

Comment: Open the .xib file in IB, in Simulated User Interface Elements add a statusBar

Comment: When i open my main menu screen, it already contains a status bar that is the status bar option in Simulated User Interface is set to Gray.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens for the root view. Instead of using the addSubView method, try setting the window's rootViewController. Something like this:

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
     **window.rootViewController = [[Resources getResources] *getSplashViewController*]];**
     [vindow makeKeyAndVisible];
     [self performSelector:@selector(displayMainMenuView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
  }

  -(void) displayMainMenuView {
     **window.rootViewController = [[Resources getResources] *getMainMenuViewController*]];**
  }

Please note that you should set the controller object, not the view object. Thus you'd need getters like getMainMenuViewController in your case.